# Making a scrollable TableLayout display a message if it is empty

Tags: android

I have a TableLayout embedded in a ScrollView so it can scroll. It is set up like this (nothing really special about it):

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/rejectDataTypeButton"
    android:layout_above="@id/datalist_nextButton" >

    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/dataListTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1" />

</ScrollView>
```

How do I make it display a message if it is empty, similar to the way [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) does it? Is it even possible, since the TableLayout does not have a `.setEmptyView(View)` method like `ListView` has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could however do it in Java, and if your Array/Result/Whatever is empty, you add a new `TableRow` with your information message.

The best place to do this (testing if your data-set is empty and displaying the information) is in the `onStart`-method, thought.